# Inject CDI managed bean in SystemEventListener

Tags: jsf, cdi, managed-bean, systemeventlistener

I have used answer of [How to disable elements from within a ViewHandler after jsf has embedded the composite component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15029135/how-to-disable-elements-from-within-a-viewhandler-after-jsf-has-embedded-the-com/15031242#15031242) to programmatically disable all components in all forms. A `SystemEventListener` catches and disables all components.

What I would like to add is getting some logic from a CDI bean. It appears that I cannot `@Inject` a CDI bean inside `SystemEventListener`. Is there some other mechanism to get logic from CDI beans? I have lots of components and it would be very time consuming to add `disabled="#{bean.disabled}"` to all components. As I understand this is the right approach to "batch disable" or I'm heavily mistaken here?

Comment: Check the omnifaces [`o:massAttribute`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/taghandlers/massAttribute)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you're not using JSF 2.2 yet. Since that version, a lot of JSF artifacts have been made eligible for CDI injection, including `SystemEventListener` instances. See also [What's new in JSF 2.2? - Issue 763](http://jdevelopment.nl/jsf-22/#763). If you're running JSF 2.0/2.1 on a Servlet 3.0 capable container, then it should be a minimum of effort to upgrade to JSF 2.2.

If you can't upgrade for some reason, then you can always programmatically grab the CDI managed bean via JNDI. The CDI `BeanManager` instance is available at JNDI name `java:comp/BeanManager`. Once having it at hands, use the below `getReference()` utility method to obtain the reference of interest.

```
public static <T> T getReference(BeanManager beanManager, Class<T> beanClass) {
    Bean<T> bean = resolve(beanManager, beanClass);
    return (bean != null) ? getReference(beanManager, bean) : null;
}

public static <T> Bean<T> resolve(BeanManager beanManager, Class<T> beanClass) {
    Set<Bean<?>> beans = beanManager.getBeans(beanClass);

    for (Bean<?> bean : beans) {
        if (bean.getBeanClass() == beanClass) {
            return (Bean<T>) beanManager.resolve(Collections.<Bean<?>>singleton(bean));
        }
    }

    return (Bean<T>) beanManager.resolve(beans);
}

public static <T> T getReference(BeanManager beanManager, Bean<T> bean) {
    return (T) beanManager.getReference(bean, bean.getBeanClass(), beanManager.createCreationalContext(bean));
}
```

*(source code from [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org) [`Beans`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/utils/Beans)/[`BeansLocal`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/utils/BeansLocal))*

So, in a nutshell:

```
BeanManager beanManager = (BeanManager) new InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/BeanManager");
YourBean yourBean = getReference(beanManager, YourBean.class);
// ...
```

Or, if you're already using OmniFaces 1.x, or are open to using it, use its `Beans` utility class (available since 1.6 only):

```
YourBean yourBean = Beans.getReference(YourBean.class);
// ...
```

Both return a proxy reference, you could safely assign it as an instance variable of the `SystemEventListener` class during its construction.