# How to disable all components for the same type in a JSF page

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, disabled-control

I have let's said 4 pages who are dynamically included by a for like this:

```
      <c:forEach items="#{tareaController.mfuncionesAsociadas}" var="mFuncion" varStatus="loop1">                    
             <p:tab id="t_funcion_#{loop1.index}" title="#{mFuncion.nombre}"  >
                   <f:subview id="tab_#{loop1.index}">
                        <p:panelGrid id="pg_funcion_#{loop1.index}">
                           <ui:include src="#{mFuncion.paginaFuncion}"></ui:include>
                        </p:panelGrid>
                   </f:subview>
             </p:tab>
      </c:forEach>
```

I want to do the following: on every page I generate could be read only, by a boolean in the database.
Obviously I can get that done just by disable=variable in every input component on every single page. But I want to know if there's a most elegant way to get this done for let's say all inputText or all inputTextarea in the same page, or if there's a way to get all input elements of a page into an array where I can modify its properties.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org) [`<o:massAttribute>`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/taghandlers/massAttribute) for this.

```
<o:massAttribute target="javax.faces.component.UIInput" name="disabled" value="#{bean.disabled}">
    <ui:include ... />
</o:massAttribute>
```

An alternative is a `SystemEventListener` as answered in this question: [How to disable elements from within a ViewHandler after jsf has embedded the composite component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15029135/how-to-disable-elements-from-within-a-viewhandler-after-jsf-has-embedded-the-com) But that would apply on the entire web application and you'd need to perform a conditional check.

Comment: Wow, that OmniFaces massAttribute is exactly what I need, yet I tried that and OmniFaces asked me for CDI but I'm using Apache Tomcat 7.0.41.0, and sadly, I can't upgrade it or modify its default settings just for one tag :( Is there a way for use the SystemEventListener and pull that event then do the check whenever a page is included?

Comment: 2.x indeed requires CDI. Use version 1.x (currently latest available is 1.10).

Comment: My mistake, I tried downloading the 1.1 version and that tag throw me error. I'm gonna try it, sorry!

Comment: It was added in 1.8. Edit: ah OK, nevermind then :) Go ahead with 1.10.

Comment: You sir, are a genius. Next time I'm just gonna knock your door, everytime I have a question you answer it.

Comment: You're welcome. Explore and enjoy OmniFaces, it offers many other handy goodies/utilities.

Comment: Good advertising, sir.

Comment: @BalusC can I filter out some `UIInput`s I do not want to change, for example checking one of its css classes?